# Multiple Tables for one Django Model

Tags: django, django-models, multiple-tables

How can I dynamically create multiple tables for one specific model?
I have a model (e.g. "Data") and want each user to get a separate database table for this model.

There will be between 30 and 40 users, each with about 20 million entries in "Data". So that the database table does not get 800 million rows, I would like to split it.
Of course, it is also possible that there will be more in the future

Is this still possible with Django ORM?
I'm on PostgreSQL

Thanks :)

Comment: This does not sound like a good implementation practice, nor it follows Normalization rules. Rather have some indexing if required, may be based on user.

Comment: This is a very bad approach imagine that you want to make a search from that model ,it is all always easy to search from one table that differents ones,the best approach will be to have an index on a column to help you deal with speed and when  you will have a lot of datas then you can just use sharding (https://github.com/JBKahn/django-sharding#:~:text=Sharding%20is%20a%20way%20of,read%20performance%20of%20your%20application) i think sharding is what you need.

Comment: It would not be necessary to search the tables together. Each user needs only his own table. Like a tenant system

Answer (score 1):

For a strict requirement, I had to go through this. I will just leave my solution here for future reference.
After **User** creation, let's say we want to create a "**user_data_100**" table with model "UserData" with pgsql database.
**Note**: here **"100"** is the "User" model(table entries) primary key value.

in app/model.py create the user model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver 
from django.db import connection
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserData(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        pass

    dt_column_one = models.CharField(max_length=10,)
    dt_column_two = models.CharField(max_length=5,)

def create_model_by_prototype(model_name, schema_name, tbl_name, prototype):
    import copy
    class Meta:
        pass
    setattr(Meta, "db_table", schema_name + "\".\"" + table_name)
    fields = {}
    for field in prototype._meta.fields:
        fields[field.name] = copy.deepcopy(field)

    attrs = {'__module__': "app.models.models", 'Meta': Meta}
    attrs.update(fields)
    model = type(model_name, (models.Model,), attrs)

    return model
```

**Note**: function "create_model_by_prototype" will generate a model with **given** table name.

Now let's use the function. I assume the user will get created from the admin site. Let's create a post_save function to create UserData table.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_data_table(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
print('User post save')

if kwargs['created']: 
    user_id = instance.id
    dy_table_name = "user_data_" + str(user_id)
    model= create_model_by_prototype("MyUserData", "public", dy_table_name, UserData)
    with connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor: schema_editor.create_model(model)
else:
    print('updated')
```

hope this works for you. Thanks.